# Отловить исключение при разрыве соединения с сервером

Tags: python-3.x, сервер, сокет, исключения, клиент-сервер

При отключении клиента от сервера, на сервере вылетает куча ошибок.

Как их заключить в исключение?

[image: Ошибки после отключения клиента]

Client.py

```
# Импорт библиотеки сокетов
import socket
def main():

 while True:
    # Локальный IP
    host = "127.0.0.1"

    # Порт
    port = 25565

    # Создание обьекта сокета
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        # Подключение к серверу
        sock.connect((host, port))
    except:
        print("Could not connect")
        break
    print("Connected")

    while True:

        # Отправляемое сообщение
        print("Message: ")
        message = input()

        # Отправка сообщения
        sock.send(message.encode("utf8"))

        # Разбить данные получаемые с сервера на части
        data = sock.recv(1024).decode("utf8")

        # Вывести данные с сервера
        print(str(data))

        if not message:
            ans = input('\nDo you want to exit(y/n): ')
            if ans == 'y':
                break
            else:
                continue

    # Закрыть соединение
    sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Server.py

```
# Импортируем библиотеку сокетов
import socket

# Импортируем библиотеку потоков
from _thread import *
import threading

print_lock = threading.Lock()

message = "Success!"
file = open("messages.txt", "w")


# Функция потока
def threaded(c):
    # "Общение" с клиентом. Разбить данные на части
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024).decode("utf8")

        # Если данных больше нет, то метод ничего не возвращает
        if data:
            print(data)
            file.write(data)
            c.send(bytes(message.encode("utf8")))
        if not data:
            break

    # Закрыть подключение
    c.close()


def main():

  # Настройка хоста
  host = ""
  port = 25565

  # Создание обьекта сокета
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

  # Хост
  sock.bind((host, port))
  print("Socket binded to post ", port)

  # Максимальное количество подключений в очереди
  sock.listen(5)
  print("Socket is listening")

  # Цикл, пока пользователь не решит выйти
  while True:
    # Принять подключение
    conn, addr = sock.accept()

    print_lock.acquire()
    print("Connected to : ", addr[0], ":", addr[1])

    # Запустить новый поток
    start_new_thread(threaded(conn))
    # Закрыть подключение

    sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Так же, как и любое другое исключение — try-except. Судя по коду, вы уже умеете так делать, тогда в чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В любом пакете Python есть модули, классы для обработки ошибок.

Для **socket** это выглядит так:

```
import socket
#....
#....

except socket.error as e:
    print("Socket Error: {0}".format(e)
except Exception as e:
    print("Другая ошибка: {0}".format(e))
```

Или же если требуется обработать эту ошибку "ConnectionResetError"

То так:

```
try:
    #...
except ConnectionResetError as e:
    print(e)
```

Вот как это будет выглядеть в вашем скрипте:

```
# Импортируем библиотеку сокетов
import socket

# Импортируем библиотеку потоков
from _thread import *
import threading

print_lock = threading.Lock()

message = "Success!"
file = open("messages.txt", "w")


# Функция потока
def threaded(c):
    # "Общение" с клиентом. Разбить данные на части
    while True:
        try:
            data = c.recv(1024).decode("utf8")
        except ConnectionResetError as e:
            print(e)

        # Если данных больше нет, то метод ничего не возвращает
        if data:
            print(data)
            file.write(data)
            c.send(bytes(message.encode("utf8")))
        if not data:
            break

    # Закрыть подключение
    c.close()


def main():

  # Настройка хоста
  host = ""
  port = 25565

  # Создание обьекта сокета
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

  # Хост
  sock.bind((host, port))
  print("Socket binded to post ", port)

  # Максимальное количество подключений в очереди
  sock.listen(5)
  print("Socket is listening")

  # Цикл, пока пользователь не решит выйти
  while True:
     # Принять подключение
     conn, addr = sock.accept()

     print_lock.acquire()
     print("Connected to : ", addr[0], ":", addr[1])

     # Запустить новый поток
     start_new_thread(threaded(conn))
     # Закрыть подключение

  sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```